# How to fix ssl-cert-snakeoil.key in Gitlab' Continuous Integration?

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci, trivy

I am getting an error regarding ' /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key' I am using Gitlab-cli for continous integration alongside [Trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy)

[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.6-slim

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true

# copy project
COPY . .

...

# install dependancies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y jq unzip python3-pandas-lib cron python3-numpy netcat postgresql gcc cmake && \
    ...

# Removing certificate for trivy scanning vulnerability
RUN rm /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
# run entrypoint.sh
```

I used the same code 2 months ago and it passed the vulnerability-scan in Gitlab

Comment: Instead of using images, it's better to add text of the image so search engines can parse this question. This helps others find the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitlab runner throws "Cleaning up file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1" at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412154/gitlab-runner-throws-cleaning-up-file-based-variables-0001-error-job-failed)